# How to get a list of object keys in JMESPath

Tags: json, jmespath

My Google search skills are failing me. How to get a list of all JSON object keys in JMESPath?

i.e. how to go from:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

to:

```
["a", "b"]
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JMESPath has the function [`keys`](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys). Therefore, the JMESPath expression is `keys(@)`.

### Example

```
echo '{"a": 1, "b": 2}' | jp "keys(@)"
```

returns

```
[
  "a",
  "b"
]
```

Tested with [`jp`](https://github.com/jmespath/jp) 0.1.3 on a Linux environment.